# code change - using python2 changing to python3

Tags: python, networking, twisted

This is a piece of Sample code from O'Reily Twisted Network programming essentials book. the line `"h = HeadlineRetriever()` is causing issues. The error log says 'HeadlineRetriever' is not defined. Is this due to changes in py3? How would I fix the issue?

Tried: unindenting the line `h = HeadlineRetrieveer()` but then the line `d.addCallbacks(printData, printError)` Did not recognize parameters.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

    class HeadlineRetriever(object):
        def processHeadline(self, headline):
            if len(headline) > 50:
                self.d.errback(
                    b"The headline ''%s'' is too long!" % (headline,))
            else:
                self.d.callback(headline)

        def _toHTML(self, result):
            return "<h1>%s</h1>" % (result,)

        def getHeadline(self, input):
            self.d = defer.Deferred()
            reactor.callLater(1, self.processHeadline, input)
            self.d.addCallback(self._toHTML)
            return self.d

        def printData(result):
            print(result)
            reactor.stop()

        def printError(failure):
            print(failure)
            reactor.stop()

        h = HeadlineRetriever()
        d = h.getHeadline("Breaking News: Twisted Takes Us to the Moon!")
        d.addCallbacks(printData, printError)

        reactor.run()
```

Error log: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/Users/jessica/Twisted/3.4asynchronousHeadlineRetriever.py", line 3, in <module>
    class HeadlineRetriever(object):
  File "C:/Users/jessica/Twisted/3.4asynchronousHeadlineRetriever.py", line 28, in HeadlineRetriever
    h = HeadlineRetriever()
NameError: name 'HeadlineRetriever' is not defined
```

Comment: you are calling it inside the suite, reduce the indentation of the those line `h = HeadlineRetriever()` so that its outside the indentation of the class declaration

Comment: @The Wolf when I did this. teh line "d.addCallbacks(printData, print Error) didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Show the traceback.

Comment: @BoarGules Traceback (most recent call last):
    d.addCallbacks(printData, printError)
NameError: name 'printData' is not defined

Comment: You need to reduce the indentation of all of the lines after `h = HeadlineRetriever()` as well.

Comment: @cdarke when i do that i get the traceback error of:     d.addCallbacks(printData, printError)
NameError: name 'printData' is not defined

Comment: assuming you have un-indented all lines after and including `h = HeadlineRetriever()`. Replace `d.addCallbacks(printData, printError)` with `d.addCallbacks(h.printData, h.printError)`

Comment: `printData` and `printError` are methods of `HeadlineRetriever`. You have an instance of `HeadlineRetriever` called `h`. If you want to refer to those methods outside the class, then you need to do `d.addCallbacks(h.printData, h.printError)`.

Comment: @BoarGules and The Wolf thank you that fixed the error. But now, the terminal is just running it doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

        class HeadlineRetriever(object):
            def processHeadline(self, headline):
                if len(headline) > 50:
                    self.d.errback(
                        b"The headline ''%s'' is too long!" % (headline,))
                else:
                    self.d.callback(headline)

            def _toHTML(self, result):
                return "<h1>%s</h1>" % (result,)

            def getHeadline(self, input):
                self.d = defer.Deferred()
                reactor.callLater(1, self.processHeadline, input)
                self.d.addCallback(self._toHTML)
                return self.d

            def printData(self, result):
                print(result)
                reactor.stop()

            def printError(self, failure):
                print(failure)
                reactor.stop()

  h = HeadlineRetriever()
  d = h.getHeadline("Breaking News: Twisted Takes Us to the Moon!")
  d.addCallbacks(h.printData, h.printError)

  reactor.run()
```

The printError and print data functions needed self as the first paramteter and in the call.
`d.adCallbacks(printData, printError)` those needed to be `d.addcallbacks(h.printData, h.printError)`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an identation mistake starting when you define h and in the class itself

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

class HeadlineRetriever(object):
    def processHeadline(self, headline):
        if len(headline) > 50:
            self.d.errback(
                b"The headline ''%s'' is too long!" % (headline,))
        else:
            self.d.callback(headline)

    def _toHTML(self, result):
        return "<h1>%s</h1>" % (result,)

    def getHeadline(self, input):
        self.d = defer.Deferred()
        reactor.callLater(1, self.processHeadline, input)
        self.d.addCallback(self._toHTML)
        return self.d

    def printData(result):
        print(result)
        reactor.stop()

    def printError(failure):
        print(failure)
        reactor.stop()

h = HeadlineRetriever()
d = h.getHeadline("Breaking News: Twisted Takes Us to the Moon!")
d.addCallbacks(printData, printError)

reactor.run()
```

This should work

Comment: How is that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

Maybe you're missing the `__init__` method, also, maintain your code indented at the left margin, if it isn't, may cause your code to be a little buggy.

Try to add:

```
 def __init__(self):
            pass
```

See if it works, then update me.

Cheers!